# How can I set the status of my user before logging into a multi user chat with slixmpp or sleekxmpp?

Tags: python

I have been using a python script that uses slixmpp. I want to set my status into another, that is different from avaible. For example:" busy" or "I'm not here". I tried to modify the send_presence() method into: "self.send_presence(pstatus="I am away",pshow='away')" but nothing is changed.
The script that I modified is this: https://slixmpp.readthedocs.io/getting_started/muc.html 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps posting what you've tried and what you have right now would yield better help from the community?